# Where to get replacement parts for a Ugly Stik GX2 fishing rod

Tags: fishing

Where can I get a handle for my Ugly Stik GX2. My handle fell off into the lake. I found the screw on the other side but the handle is gone. I couldn't find a single replacement parts dealer so far.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend contacting an Ugly Stick service department directly and asking them if they can send you a replacement part, there's a chance your rod may even be covered by warranty:

http://www.uglystik.com/UglyStik-warranty-service.html

IN THE U.S.

Shakespeare® Customer Service
1900 18th Street
Spirit Lake, IA 51360
(800) 466-5643

IN CANADA

Mike’s Tackle Repair
#108-31060 Peardonville Rd.
Abbotsford, BC V2T 6K5
(604) 855-1119

Rockey’s Tackle Repair
10 Brammer Drive
Orilla, ON L3V 7T4
(705) 325-3526